# Java Path finder: How to access it through command terminal?

Tags: java, windows, cmd, jpf

I am new to Java. I have to detect bugs in a java (KLOC) program. For which I am using Java Path finder. I am running it through commandline `cmd`. Using the command

```
java -jar build/RunJPF.jar  C:\Users\xxx\yyy\src\main\java\zzz.jpf
```

I wanted to know, how can I:

1. Get the race conditions
2. detects deadlock
3. verify controlling
4. verify controlling JPF,Search
5. Check for Numerical Extensions

All in the command line?
It would be really helpful if the above questions can be answered using an example.

Thanks

Comment: [Running JPF](http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki/user/run#command-line)

Comment: collected native_libraries=null
[SEVERE] JPF configuration error: no target class specified, terminating
> used within "vm.class" instantiation of class gov.nasa.jpf.vm.SingleProcessVM
[SEVERE] JPF terminated

Comment: I get this error when I run -log command, how to fix this?